# Threads com tamanho definido via código

Tags: delphi, thread, delphi-2007

Tenho um sistema que em certos momentos chega a utilizar mais de mil *threads* simultâneas e infelizmente **precisa** rodar em ambiente **32-bits**.

Por *default*, o **Delphi** aloca 1kb para cada *thread* nova, o que, em um ambiente **32-bits** se torna inviável para o porte do sistema em questão.
Eu poderia definir um novo valor via menu, porém perderia a opção de mudá-lo em tempo de execução, caso o novo tamanho não atenda às minhas demandas ou seja grande demais para elas.

Minha intenção então é achar uma forma, utilizando o comando `Thread.Execute` de parametrizar esse tamanho. Seja via **ini**, **BD** ou o que for, contanto que seja no código.

Sei que com o comando `BeginThread()` alcançaria meu objetivo, porém com ele acabo perdendo várias funcionalidades interessantes de threads, como o `Thread.Synchronize` e o `Thread.Queue`, que, mais uma vez, levando em conta o porte do projeto, o peso dessas perdas se faz enorme.

Um exemplo setando via *hardcode* mesmo já seria o suficiente, uma vez que já tenho a forma de parametrizar este valor definida.

Comment: Mais de mil threads simultâneas me parece excessivo. Talvez seria melhor você criar uma Thread-pool, não? O que fazem essas threads?

Comment: Quando você tem uma fila de quase 70.000 comandos simultâneos, um pool de 1.000 não parece tão excessivo. Acredito que tudo dependa do referencial.

Comment: Acredito que muita coisa dependa do referencial e por isso eu lhe pedi mais informações sobre o assunto sem condenar o seu trabalho. O que eu sei é que 1000 threads simultâneas é, em geral, exagero se você não possui um cluster de [500 cores](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888856/460775). Sem mais informações fica difícil de poder ajudar pois eu particularmente não gosto de arriscar em chutes.

Comment: Meu comentário de forma alguma foi pejorativo, @EMBarbosa, muito pelo contrário. Pela impossibilidade de passar mais informações, eu realmente falhei em explicar o porquê de tantas threads simultâneas, portanto neste momento só fiz corrigir meu erro anterior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma de resolver meu problema sem apelar para o `BeginThread`.
Segue:

No início do meu projeto eu posso definir o tamanho de todas as `threads` do sistema, consequentemente as criadas pelo método `Thread.Execute`.

Ao adicionar as linhas:

```
{$MINSTACKSIZE 16384}
{$MAXSTACKSIZE 65536}
```

Desta forma:
[image: Unit Stress]

Defino o tamanho mínimo e máximo de cada thread.

---

### Segue evidência:

> **Antes:**
>   [image: Antes]
>   *Stack size 1.000Kb*
>   **Depois:**
>   [image: Depois]
>   *Stack size 64Kb*

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente a classe [`TThread`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TThread.html) não permite configurar o tamanho de pilha da *thread*. O único modo para alcançar isso seria utilizar a função [`BeginThread`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.BeginThread), porém como você disse não é viável em seu caso.

> function BeginThread(SecurityAttributes: Pointer; **`StackSize`**: LongWord; ThreadFunc: TThreadFunc; Parameter: Pointer; CreationFlags: LongWord; var ThreadId: TThreadID): THandle;

Inclusive há sugestões para mudar isso veja([`Permitir que o tamanho da pilha seja especificado ao criar a thread`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=77203) - *Embarcadero*).

O relatório foi emitido em *2009* quem sabe num futuro próximo isso seja um característica. :)

Comment: É... Ao que parece não existe solução. Agradeço o empenho. +1

Comment: C. Encontrei uma forma! Realmente, parametrizar **na função** é impossível, mas dá pra definir o tamanho para todas as threads e isso me resolve o problema. Agradeço imensamente pela ajuda!